# Turbolinks not rendering code on page change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using Segment.io to do tracking on my site. We have a live chat widget that I'd like to be displayed on every page. However I'm unable to figure out how to make this work.

I've created an `analytics.js` which loads in the body (I've also tried adding the analytics.page(); to the body without any results):

```
  window.analytics = window.analytics || [];

  window.analytics.methods = ['identify', 'group', 'track',
    'page', 'pageview', 'alias', 'ready', 'on', 'once', 'off',
    'trackLink', 'trackForm', 'trackClick', 'trackSubmit'];

  window.analytics.factory = function(method){
    return function(){
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(method);
      window.analytics.push(args);
      return window.analytics;
    };
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < window.analytics.methods.length; i++) {
    var key = window.analytics.methods[i];
    window.analytics[key] = window.analytics.factory(key);
  }

  window.analytics.load = function(key){
    if (document.getElementById('analytics-js')) return;

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.id = 'analytics-js';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol
      ? 'https://' : 'http://')
      + 'cdn.segment.io/analytics.js/v1/'
      + key + '/analytics.min.js';

    var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
  };

  window.analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION = '3.1.0';
  window.analytics.load('kYDWuP6nxI');
  window.analytics.page();

  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    console.log('page change');
    analytics.page();
  });
```

When I visit a new page on the app it shows the console log, but `analytics.page();` doesn't seem to be rendered except when I do a manual page refresh.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: replace `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {` with `$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: that returns Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Had to go look for this repo for you. Helped me a while back with something similar. Might help https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/segmentio.js

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Turbolinks 5 :(